# Alexa Skill python not working properly with NoIntent

Tags: python, alexa-skills-kit

I am a basic dev with Alexa Skill, and with Python, but cannot understand where is the problem.
This skill ask the start and the end of a shower, to calculate expenses and energy consumption.

When user finish the shower, I ask "Alexa take the shower" than Alexa asks:

- Have you finished the shower? ("YES")
- Have you used the hairdryer?

When user replies "NO" to the last question, Alexa doesn't understand.
When, instead, the reply is "YES" everything is fine.

What is wrong in code?
Thanks

```
class ValidateShowerIntentHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """Handler for Hello World Intent."""
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
        return ask_utils.is_intent_name("ValidateShowerIntent")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
        persistent_attributes = handler_input.attributes_manager.persistent_attributes
        if 'startedShower' not in persistent_attributes:
            speak_output = "Ciao, ora calcoliamo il costo della tua doccia. Stai iniziando la doccia?"
        else:
            speak_output = "Hai finito la doccia?"

        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
                .speak(speak_output)
                .ask(speak_output)
                .response
        )
        
class YesIntentHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """Handler for Help Intent."""
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
        return ask_utils.is_intent_name("AMAZON.YesIntent")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        logger.info("inside YesIntentHandler()")
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
        persistent_attributes = handler_input.attributes_manager.persistent_attributes
        if 'total_minutes' in persistent_attributes:
            # dryer is used
            minutes = persistent_attributes['total_minutes']
            # calculation
            total_cost = (int(minutes) + 5 ) * 0.07
            userId = handler_input.request_envelope.context.system.user.user_id
            print(userId)
            item = {
                "guid" : str(uuid.uuid4()),
                "created_on" : datetime.utcnow().strftime(DATETIME_FORMAT),
                "user_id": userId,
                "total_minutes": minutes,
                "is_dryer_used": True,
                "total_cost": round(decimal.Decimal(total_cost),3)
            }
            print(item)
            tms_skill_table.put_item(Item = item)
            total_cost_round_off = round(total_cost,3)
            speak_output = f"Il totale per la tua doccia \u00E8 di {total_cost_round_off} EUR"
            # Delete all attributes from the DB
            handler_input.attributes_manager.delete_persistent_attributes()
        elif 'startedShower' not in persistent_attributes:
            persistent_attributes['startedShower'] = "yes"
            start_time = datetime.utcnow().strftime(DATETIME_FORMAT)
            print(start_time)
            persistent_attributes['startTime'] = start_time
            # Write user's name to the DB.
            handler_input.attributes_manager.save_persistent_attributes()
            speak_output = "Okay"
        else:
            start_time = datetime.strptime(persistent_attributes['startTime'], DATETIME_FORMAT)
            current_time = datetime.utcnow()
            time_taken = current_time - start_time
            minutes = time_taken.total_seconds() / 60
            print(minutes)
            persistent_attributes['total_minutes'] = str(round(minutes))
            speak_output = f"Hai usato un asciugacapelli?"
            
            handler_input.attributes_manager.save_persistent_attributes()
            logger.info(f"Alexa message - {speak_output}")
            logger.info(f"session_attributes - {persistent_attributes}")
            return (
                handler_input.response_builder
                    .speak(speak_output)
                    .ask(speak_output)
                    .response
            )
        
        logger.info(f"Alexa message - {speak_output}")
        logger.info(f"session_attributes - {persistent_attributes}")
        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
                .speak(speak_output)
                .set_should_end_session(True)
                .response
        )
        
class NoIntentHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """Handler for Help Intent."""
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
        return ask_utils.is_intent_name("AMAZON.NoIntent")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        logger.info("inside NoIntentHandler()")
        persistent_attributes = handler_input.attributes_manager.persistent_attributes
        if 'total_minutes' in persistent_attributes:
            # dryer is used
            minutes = persistent_attributes['total_minutes']
            # calculation
            total_cost = int(minutes) * 0.07
            userId = handler_input.request_envelope.context.system.user.user_id
            print(userId)
            item = {
                "guid" : str(uuid.uuid4()),
                "created_on" : datetime.utcnow().strftime(DATETIME_FORMAT),
                "user_id": userId,
                "total_minutes": minutes,
                "is_dryer_used": False,
                "total_cost": decimal.Decimal(total_cost)
            }
            tms_skill_table.put_item(Item = item)
            speak_output = f"Il totale per la tua doccia \u00E8 di {total_cost} EUR"
            logger.info(f"Alexa message - {speak_output}")
            logger.info(f"session_attributes - {persistent_attributes}")
            # Delete all attributes from the DB
            handler_input.attributes_manager.delete_persistent_attributes()
            persistent_attributes = {}
            return (
                handler_input.response_builder
                    .speak(speak_output)
                    .set_should_end_session(True)
                    .response
            )
        speak_output = "Okay. Secondo te come posso aiutarti??"
        reprompt = f"Forse non hai capito: devi dire: inizio la doccia. "
        logger.info(f"Alexa message - {speak_output}")
        logger.info(f"session_attributes - {persistent_attributes}")
        persistent_attributes = {}
        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
                .speak(speak_output)
                .ask(reprompt)
                .response
        )
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
logger.info("inside YesIntentHandler()") 
# type: (HandlerInput) -&gt; Response 
persistent_attributes = handler_input.attributes_manager.persistent_attributes
if 'total_minutes' in persistent_attributes:
    # dryer is used 
    minutes = persistent_attributes['total_minutes'] 
    # calculation
    total_cost = (int(minutes) + 5 ) * 0.07
    userId = handler_input.request_envelope.context.system.user.user_id 
    print(userId)
    item = {
```

Comment: Cannot understand, it seems to be the same code

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).